# Ember.js: Child records not rendered after switching between different routes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a list of tasks. Each task has a list of bullets (child items) next to it. 
The bullets can be toggled.

I have 2 routes for displaying only completed and active tasks.
Displaying the tasks itself and switching between routes work always fine, the bullets are also shown.

Problem:

- First click on a child item works as well --> bullet gets toggled.
- Second click on a child item and NONE of the child records are
  rendered anymore.

When I remove DayCompletedRoute & DayActiveRoute the bullets get rendered again.

Why is it not working with multiple routes?

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('days', {path: "/"}, function () {

        this.resource('day', {path: "/days/:day_id"}, function () {
            this.route('active');
            this.route('completed');
        })
        this.route('new', {path: "/days/new"});

    });
});


// ROUTES
App.DaysRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('day');
    }
});

App.DayRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (day) {
        return this.store.find('day', day.day_id);
    }
});

App.DayIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.modelFor('day');
    }
});

App.DayCompletedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
         return this.modelFor('day').get('tasks').then(function(tasks){
             return tasks.filterBy('isCompleted', true);
         });
    }
});

App.DayActiveRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('day').get('tasks').then(function(tasks){
            return tasks.rejectBy('isCompleted', true);
        });
    },
    renderTemplate: function(controller) {
        this.render('day/completed', {controller: controller});
    }
});
```

Template Snippets:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
// navigation here
       {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="days/new">...</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="days">   
    {{outlet}}   
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="day">
    {{input type="text" placeholder="What needs to be done?" value=newTitle action="createTask"}}
    {{outlet}}

    {{#link-to "day.index" activeClass="selected"}}All{{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to "day.completed" activeClass="selected"}}Completed{{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to "day.active" activeClass="selected"}}Active{{/link-to}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="day/index">
    {{#each task in this.tasks}}
        {{task.title}}
        {{#each item in task.sortedItems}}                  
            {{input type="checkbox" checked=item.filled}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="day/completed">
    {{#each itemController="task"}}
        {{title}}
        {{#each item in sortedItems}}                         
            {{input type="checkbox" checked=item.filled}}           
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the `{{outlet}}`?

Comment: Can you create a failing bin?

Comment: I found what is triggering the error. In the task model I have a function to save changes: 

App.Task = DS.Model.extend({...some properties... isChanged: function () { this.save(); }.observes('isCompleted') }); when I comment this.save() out the bullets stay. but then the task's property isCompleted isn't persistet anymore. Saving the task in the controller didn't work so far. Where should I save it?